# Ordering view by document type in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have diferent kinds of documents in my couchDB, for example:

```
{
   "_id": "c9f3ebc1-78f4-4dd1-8fc2-ab96f804287c",
   "_rev": "7-1e8fcc048237366e24869dadc9ba54f1",
   "to_customer": false,

   "box_type": {
       "id": 9,
       "name": "ZF3330"
   },
   "erp_creation_date": "16/12/2017",
   "type": "pallet",
   "plantation": {
       "id": 62,
       "name": "FRF"
   },
   "pallet_type": {
       "id": 2565,
       "name": "ZF15324"
   },
   "creation_date": "16/12/2017",

   "article_id": 3,
   "updated": "2017/12/16 19:01",
   "server_status": {
       "in_server": true,
       "errors": null,
       "modified_in_server": false,
       "dirty": false,
       "delete_in_server": false
   },

   "pallet_article": {
       "id": 11,
       "name": "BLUE"
   }
}
```

So , in all my documents, I have the field : `type`. In the other hand I have a view that get all the documents whose type is `pallet || shipment`

this is my view:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.completed == true && (doc.type == "shipment" || doc.type == "pallet" )){  
        emit([doc.type, doc.device_num, doc.num], doc);
    }
}
```

So in this view I get always a list with the view query result, the problem  I have is that list is ordering by receiving date(I guess) and I need to order it by document type.
so my question is: How Can I order documents by `document.type` in a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View results are always sorted by key, so your view is sorted by `doc.type`: first you will get all pallets, then all the shipments. the pallets are sorted by `device_num` and then `num`. If you emit several rows with the same keys, the rows are then sorted by _id. You can find more detailed info in the [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html).

So your view should actually work the way you want. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernhard in other to do the viceverse I mean first shipment and then palets , what I have to do?

Comment: @JoCuTo You can either emit a custom value as the first element of the key (`emit([doc.type==='shipment' ? '0-shipment' : doc.type, …`), or you can reverse the order of the complete view result at query time by appending `descending=true` to the view url.